# Python: Displaying recurring events in ics files as multiple events

Tags: python, calendar, icalendar, rrule

I am trying to parse an .ics (which I exported from Google calendar) using Python and the iCalendar package. My final goal is to produce a simple list of [time, event name] tuples.

I am currently having an issue because I have a few recurring events in my calendar. These events have are reflected with RRule's in the .ics file that look like:

RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=35;BYDAY=TH

Is there any package or simple code that I could use to represent each recurring event as multiple events? I am currently making a lot of errors when I try to write code to parse the RRULE part of the .ics file and create multiple events myself.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Still don't know how to do it without a mess of code. A simple solution would be great...